# Is there any perforce plugin for dreamweaver CS5

Tags: perforce, dreamweaver

I want to know if there is any perforce plugin which would work with Dreamweaver CS5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present Dreamweaver does not support perforce directory though photoshop does, you might like to use P4FTP allows FTP clients, including Dreamweaver, to access Perforce depot files via FTP.  It can be installed in addition to or instead of an FTP server on Unix or Windows NT/2000.

refer following for more info...

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.032/manuals/p4ftp/01_install.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not - there is only SVN support out-of-the-box. It would be possible to write an Adobe Extension that integrates P4 into Dreamweaver. There is a project on GoogleCode that could help you get started - [SubWeaver](http://code.google.com/p/subweaver/).

HTH,